# Python - change the layout of a decision tree

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a decision tree classifier from Scikit-Learn in Python and I want to visualize (plot) a tree. I'm looking at two options: using Graphviz (by exporting the data to a text file) or to use tree.tree_plot(clf). I find both options however not very readable and I want to be able to change the visualization. R produces a much better tree in my opinion and I want to have something like that.

When looking at the Titanic data, then the R tree and Python tree are as follows:

**R**

[image]

**Python** (done in Graphviz)

[image]

Is there a way to produce a tree like the one from R?
I want to change the True and False arrows to the features itself and remove the features from the nodes itself, where it states "female <= 0.5" for example.